# PHP AJAX returning values working properly but with the wrong alert message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, alert

I have this PHP script where it counts the number of pills of a specific medication, that is working properly:

```
$clinic_id = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$visit_id = $_POST['visit_id'];
$patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
$nid = $_POST['nid'];
$did = $_POST['did'];
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$diagnosis = $_POST['diagnosis'];
$medication_id = $_POST['medication_id'];
$medication_quantity = $_POST['medication_quantity'];
$consultation_result = $_POST['consultation_result'];

$ensureQuantity = "
SELECT t1.med_pharmacy_id
     , t1.med_id
     , sum(t2.given_quantity) as given_pills
     , t1.med_tablet - ((sum(t2.given_quantity)*t1.med_tablet)/t1.med_pill) as still_tablets
     , (t1.med_pill-sum(t2.given_quantity)) as still_pills
  FROM med_pharmacy t1
     , consultation_med t2
     , medication t3 
 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id 
   AND t1.med_id = t3.med_id
   AND t1.clinic_id = :cid 
   AND t1.med_pharmacy_id = :mid
 GROUP 
    BY t1.med_pharmacy_id
     , t1.med_id
     , t3.med_name
     , t1.med_expiry
     , t1.med_barcode
     , t1.med_tablet
     , t1.med_pill
     , t1.med_received
";
$execEnsureQuantity = $conn->prepare($ensureQuantity);
$execEnsureQuantity->bindValue(':cid', $clinic_id);
$execEnsureQuantity->bindValue(':mid', $medication_id);
$execEnsureQuantity->execute();

$res = $execEnsureQuantity->fetch();
```

Then, it will compare it to the added value by a user from a text box:

```
if($res['still_pills']==0)
{
    echo "empty";
}
else if($medication_quantity > $res['still_pills'])
{
    echo "exceeded";
}
```

So if there is no more pills, I need to echo `empty` and if the user typed a number bigger than the exist one, it will echo "exceeded", then if number is logical:

```
else
{
    $addConsultation = "INSERT INTO consultation(nurse_list_id, doctor_list_id,
                    complication_name, diagnosis_id, visit_id, consultation_result, clinic_id,
                    patient_id)
                    VALUES(:nid, :did, :cid, :diagnosis, :visit_id, :consultation_result,
                    :clinic_id, :patient_id)";
    $execAddConsultation = $conn->prepare($addConsultation);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":nid", $nid);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":did", $did);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":cid", $cid);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":diagnosis", $diagnosis);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":visit_id", $visit_id);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":consultation_result", $consultation_result);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":clinic_id", $clinic_id);
    $execAddConsultation->bindValue(":patient_id", $patient_id);

    $execAddConsultation->execute();

    $lastConsultId = $conn->lastInsertId();

    $insertQuantity = "INSERT INTO consultation_med(consultation_id, med_pharmacy_id, given_quantity, date_given, clinic_id)
        VALUES(:consult_id, :mp_id, :gq, :dg, :cid)";
    $execInsertQuantity = $conn->prepare($insertQuantity);
    $execInsertQuantity->bindValue(':consult_id', $lastConsultId);
    $execInsertQuantity->bindValue(':mp_id', $res['med_pharmacy_id']);
    $execInsertQuantity->bindValue(':gq', $medication_quantity);
    $execInsertQuantity->bindValue(':dg', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $execInsertQuantity->bindValue(':cid', $clinic_id);
    $execInsertQuantity->execute();

    echo "q_added";
}
```

The script is working fine, so if I had `exceeded` or `empty`, nothing will be added or changed at the database.

My problem is in here:

```
success:function(response)
{

    if(response == "q_added")
    {
        alert("Data Added. Please add more, or close the box!");
        $("#doctor_list_id").val("select");
        $("#nurse_list_id").val("select");
        $("#complication_name_2").val("select");
        $("#diagnosis").val("select");
        $("#medication_quantity").val("");
        $("#medication_id").val("select");
        $("#consultation_result").val("");
        $("#complication_name_3").val("");
        //console.log(response);
    }
},
error:function(response)
{
    if(response == "empty")
    {
        alert("Not enough quantity in the storage!");
    }
    if(response == "exceeded")
    {
        alert("Quantity given is more than the exist quantity in stock");
    }   
    console.log(response);
}
```

if if I have at the console `exceeded` or `empty`, I will get the alert of `q_added` response.

I tried to move the following from `error` to `success` function but still the same:

```
if(response == "empty")
{
    alert("Not enough quantity in the storage!");
}
if(response == "exceeded")
{
    alert("Quantity given is more than the exist quantity in stock");
}
```

I even tried to use `if` `else if` `else` and still the same.

**EDIT**

Still having the same problem even when I changed the script to:

```
success:function(response)
{

    if(response == "q_added")
    {
        alert("Data Added. Please add more, or close the box!");
        $("#doctor_list_id").val("select");
        $("#nurse_list_id").val("select");
        $("#complication_name_2").val("select");
        $("#diagnosis").val("select");
        $("#medication_quantity").val("");
        $("#medication_id").val("select");
        $("#consultation_result").val("");
        $("#complication_name_3").val("");
        //console.log(response);
    }
    if(response == "empty")
    {
        alert("Not enough quantity in the storage!");
    }
    if(response == "exceeded")
    {
        alert("Quantity given is more than the exist quantity in stock");
    }   
    console.log(response);
},
```

Comment: This means that "empty" and "exceeded" is not error, but success messages.

Comment: If you want to get `empty` or `exceeded` in error then set the response code on server side like 500, 402, etc...

Comment: I already added them in the success function and still the same errors

Comment: Incidentally, we stopped writing SELECT queries this way in 1992. JOIN us!

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is correct but you are check the response in the error part which is wrong. use this:

```
success:function(response)
{
    if($.trim(response) == "empty")
    {
        alert("Not enough quantity in the storage!");
    }
    else if($.trim(response) == "exceeded")
    {
        alert("Quantity given is more than the exist quantity in stock");
    } 

    else if(response == "q_added")
    {
        alert("Data Added. Please add more, or close the box!");
        $("#doctor_list_id").val("select");
        $("#nurse_list_id").val("select");
        $("#complication_name_2").val("select");
        $("#diagnosis").val("select");
        $("#medication_quantity").val("");
        $("#medication_id").val("select");
        $("#consultation_result").val("");
        $("#complication_name_3").val("");
        //console.log(response);
    }  
    console.log(response);
},
error:function(xhr, status, error)
{

}
```

The error function in ajax is not the error that you are perception from php.

Error in ajax comes when your script is not working or your ajax is failing due to any reason.

Comment: I already did the changes if you can see the end of my question. But still not working

Comment: @droidnation check in the success function what you are getting in the response.

Comment: I am consoling it and I can see the `exceeded` or `empty` at the console

Comment: @droidnation I have edited the answer try that once and let me know